# rails content_for not showing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, partial, content-for

I have a :sidebar section in customers/new that I'm yielding to. The content_for section is called from a nested partial. The text "hello1" shows up, but "hello2" does not.

No errors are being thrown and I can't figure out how to troubleshoot.

Any ideas?

```
**layouts/application.haml**

.container
  - unless signed_in?
   = render "custom/account_#{current_account.id}" rescue nil
  = yield

**customers/new.haml**

= yield :sidebar

**custom/_account_2.haml**

%p hello1
- content_for :sidebar do
 %p hello2
```

Comment: what about putting an "end" after Hello2

Comment: It's HAML, it doesn't need an end statement

Comment: can you show where/how you're calling render for _account_2.haml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm fairly certain that `new.haml` gets rendered first, and then the partial, and then finally the layout. `new.haml` getting rendered first is your issue.

Comment: I tried putting the content_for block in other parts of the application, still no "hello2" appearing...

Answer (score -2):

```
- content_for :sidebar do
```

change to

```
= content_for :sidebar do
```

Comment: Nope that just prints the string, "= content_for :sidebar do"